# Handwriting Recognition - Percentage Match

Tags: machine-learning, probability, classification

I'm currently working on a senior project and we've chosen handwriting recognition.

Initially I thought that using machine learning algorithms were a good idea for this, but after the thought below I'm not so sure:

Assume you found a ransom note and had a suspect. So you went to the suspects house, arrested him, and took his documents to compare against.

Now of what I know of machine learning there is not much you can do with this, because the algorithm MUST choose a person of the set (this set only has 1 class - that being the documents of the suspect and an "unknown" class - BUT this unknown class has not been trained on). EVEN IF you had lets say 10 suspects and their documents and the 1 note, how can you be sure that one of the 10 REALLY WAS the kidnapper? (There's a chance that he was not in the set, but the machine learner is going to force the note onto someone. Correct?)

Does anyone have any thoughts on this? Am I not correct in this?

Is there a way to do this with probability?

Does anyone feel that machine learning is a good choice for this?

Comment: Fortunately for you, there's a thing called [one-class SVM](http://machinelearning.wustl.edu/mlpapers/paper_files/ManevitzY01.pdf).

Comment: There is a very large literature in DNA identification, which is a similar problem--but often with millions of candidates, not just one or ten.

Comment: Thank you for these. The one-class SVM looks promising. I'll shortly look into DNA identification techniques that will be viable options for this problem.